# jQuery.live() not working inside of a plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, bind, live

I am writing a plugin and need to live bind a click. The plugin works fine when I do a normal click bind, but not a live bind.

I've boiled the plugin down to the basics:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.liveBindTest = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).live('click', function(){
        console.log('live click');
        return false;
      });
      $(this).click(function(){
        console.log('click');
        return false;
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

When I call the plugin function on a link, only `click` is printed to my console.

What must I do in order for `live()` to work? Thanks.

Comment: I'm beginning to think the problem is I'm `live` binding to a DOM element, not a selector. Thinking I may need to `live` bind when invoking the plugin, not the plugin code itself.

Comment: Yes, that might be the problems. I have try running the code and got the same result with yours. Plugins should do it's function, and it's left to users to bind it to a selected element with any event that permitted, direct bind or using live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking this through, I realized it makes no sense to call `live` on an existing DOM element because it's already in the DOM.

Trick is to use `live` when invoking the plugin:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.liveBindTest = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(){
        console.log('click');
        return false;
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
$('a').live('click', function(){ $(this).liveBindTest(); });
```

Comment: That was the perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: please see my answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

this works without workarounds outside of the plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.liveBindTest = function () {
        return this['live']('click', function () {
            console.log('click');
            return false;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('a').liveBindTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you have 2 `click` event binded into a single object? The second bind will overwrite the `live` bind, so the `live` will never fired.

Comment: The 2 `click` events are include for the sake of example. Comment out the `click` bind, leaving the `live` bind, and the `live` bind still won't fire.

Comment: @Donny Kurnia: This is not true.  A given element can have any number of events attached and they will **all** fire when that event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I find this works (jQuery 1.5.2):

```
(function($) {
$.fn.clickTest = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
        $('.clicker').die('click').live('click', function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        });
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('body').append('<a href="#" class="clicker">click here '+$(this).attr('id')+'</a><br> ');

        });
    });
}; }) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good point of view.
Now suppose that your plugin is a sort of lightbox,and it is looking to anchor elements inside the DOM.
Usually at the dom ready you will do something like

```
$(dom_elements).myplugin();
```

What if your appending some links via jsor ajax to your page?
I don't think that rebinding using your

```
$('a').live('click', function(){ $(this).liveBindTest(); });
```

is going to be the right way!It will work but telling the truth i don't think that it will be a "best practice".
The real problem is that with jQuery 1.4.2 the live event delegation is waiting for a string('a.test') and not for an object(this).Could it be a jQuery 1.4.2 bug?